# Casting with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, casting, multiple-inheritance

If you have a void* pointer to Derived class that inherits from both `BaseA` and `BaseB`, how does the compiler cast the `void*` pointer to `BaseA*` (or `BaseB*`) without knowing that the `void*` pointer is of type `Derived`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't.  The only guarantee when casting to and from a `void*` using a `static_cast` is:

> A value of type pointer to object converted to "pointer to `cv void`" and back to the original pointer type will have its original value (C++03 §5.2.9/10).

For example, the following code is incorrect because the `void*` is cast to a type other than the original pointer type (the cast sequence is `B1*` -> `void*` -> `B2*`):

```
struct B1 { int i; };
struct B2 { int j; };

struct D : B1, B2 { };

D x;
B1*   b1ptr   = &x;
void* voidptr = b1ptr;
B2*   b2ptr   = static_cast<B2*>(voidptr);
```

Attempting to use `b2ptr` here would result in undefined behavior.  The only type to which you can safely cast `voidptr` is `B1*`, since that is the type from which the `void*` was obtained (well, or to a `char*`, since anything can be accessed via a `char*`).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't cast the `void*` pointer to anything -- you, the programmer, do.

In order to do anything useful with a `void*` pointer, you need to *explicitly* cast it to a non-`void*` pointer, and if you're wrong about what type the pointer actually points to, you enter Undefined Behavior City.

Comment: Your answer is correct. 

From my research if Derived extends BaseA and BaseB, the object is laid out in memory as |BaseA|BaseB|Derived|. Thus the pointer is pointing to the start of BaseA so casting Derived to BaseB will have you reading BaseA's members.